# How to make the objects.filter method to work with a Custom Model Field that takes in dictionaries - Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created a custom field that allows the user to pass in a dictionary. This dictionary gets saved as a string in my database. Here is the main part of my models.py class.

```
class OptionsField(models.Field):
    description = 'All options'
    #__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 2048
        kwargs['unique'] = False
        kwargs['null'] = True 
        super(OptionsField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'varchar(2048)'

    #Transforms database values to a python dictionary     
    def to_python(self, value): 
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            return value
        together = value.split(' \n')
        returnDictionary = {}
        for item in together:
            dictionaryField = item.split(' : ')
            returnDictionary[dictionaryField[0]] = dictionaryField[1]
        return returnDictionary

    #Transforms a python dictionary to database-compatible values (string)    
    def get_prep_value(self, dict): 
        databaseList = [] 
        print dict
        for key, value in dict.iteritems():
            listValue = ' : '.join([str(key), str(value)])
            databaseList.append(listValue)
        databaseList.sort()
        return ' \n'.join(databaseList) 
-------------------------------END OF CUSTOM FIELD---------------------

class MyModel(models.Model):
    options = OptionsField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'testingDB'
```

And inside my main, I can do the following

```
dictionary = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
example = MyModel(options = dictionary) 
example.save() 

example.options['ZZ'] = 'z'
example.options['a'] = 'grr'

example.save()
```

The first save puts the following in the database:

```
+----+--------+
| id | options| 
+----+--------+
|  1 | a : b  |  
|    | c : d  | 
+----+--------+
```

The second save changes the above to:

```
+----+--------+
| id | options| 
+----+--------+
|  1 | a : grr|  
|    | c : d  | 
|    | ZZ : z |
+----+--------+
```

How do I search in this database though? If I do something like 
`test=MyModel.objects.filter(options['a'] = 'b')`

I get a `SyntaxError: Keyword can't be an expression` 
I assume I have to make the method get_prep_lookup, and I've tried a bunch of things, but it doesn't seem to work.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-model-fields/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way you will be able to search using a key inside the database since the database only saves a string, what you can do is build a [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) for your table that helps handling the queries, maybe searching with regex could help, for example:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(options__regex=r'a : b')
MyModel.objects.filter(options__regex=r'.*c : d')
```

those can be your normal queries and with the manager you could take that info and use it.

Now there is a popular library used to save dictionaries in python classes which [pickles your dict](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield/), I would recommend using it.

Comment: +1 for answering :). It was when reading about managers that I decided to try my solution

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out. For anyone else that wishes to work with dictionaries in their main program with Django, this is what I had to do.

First of all, I had to uncomment the

```
__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
```

The above line makes sure that the `to_python` method is called automatically. (I don't completely understand, but it is explained in the documentation link I attached).

Afterwards I had to complete the `get_prep_lookup` method within the Field class. This is for searching purposes. This is all I did:

```
def get_prep_lookup(self, lookup_type, value):
    #value is a dictionary, eg: {'a': 'b', 'c':'d'}
    if lookup_type == 'exact':
        return self.get_prep_value(value) #this returns a 'database' string
    if lookup_type == 'contains':
        return self.get_prep_value(value) 
    if lookup_type == 'icontains':
        return self.get_prep_value(value) 
    else:
        raise TypeError('Lookup type %r not supported.' % lookup_type) 

def get_internal_type(self): 
#when creating the database, it'll make the columns CharFields
    return 'CharField'
```

And to use the class, I had to make a couple modifications in the search filter in my main program; I had to pass a dictionary.

```
#First find all objects that contain the following dictionary 
#Because it's icontains, I could also search with {'A':'b'}, 
#as it's case insensitive. __contains isn't case sensitive
test = MyModel.objects.filter(options__icontains = {'a':'b'})
#Note: could've used 'get' instead of filter above, 
#as I know that just one value has dict value {'a':'b'}

#Change as desired
test[0].options['a'] = 'grr'
test[0].options['ZZ'] = 'z'

#save
test[0].save()
```

And that's how I obtained the second table.

Note, if you miss the __icontains and just write `filter(options = {'a':'b'})` this will search for entries that **only** have the dictionary value `{'a':'b'}` and nothing else. Another note is that, of course, you can search with bigger dictionaries and it'll work.

Hope this will help some people :)